# Best way to compare a big list with another small list in java?

Tags: java, oop, optimization, arraylist

Consider I have a `listA[String]` with a 2 million records and another `listB` with 20 thousands of records.
I want to compare and check how many elements from `listB` is not contained in `listA`.

Very basic method is `listA.contains(listB[i])`. But for 20 thousand records, It will traverse `listA` for 20 thousand times and time complexity will be O(n*n).

Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Take listB and think about how to represent it using a different data structure. Can you use a hashmap or hashset?

Comment: @MichaelXu : Can you explain exactly what you want say ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @MichaelXu But perhaps he doesn't have the space available for this.  Another option would be to sort both lists alphabetically and then walk through the lists once and do the comparison.

Comment: yup, another good approach but with a 2 million record listA, an in-memory sort might be worse than a 20k element hashtable in his case.

Comment: I expect hashmap is the way to go here if he has the space.  Nice interacting with you on SO.

Comment: Maybe a [`BloomFilter`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained#BloomFilter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet` (or `LinkedHashSet` if the order of elements is important). `Set` is a collection that contains no duplicate elements and inserting/searching is much faster than searching in a `List`. You will need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

If you need a `List`, you can convert it back after the searching:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(hashset);
```